# When do I use New to instantiate a class

Tags: java, instantiation

I am just going through a tutorial and the instructor seemed to gloss over something which didn't make sense

In Java if I am looking to instantiate a new Gregorgian Date Object I would use:

```
GregorianCalendar gc= new GregorianCalendar (2010,1,14);
```

but if I am looking to use the Data Format object I would use:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
```

1. I would really like to understand why dateformat doesn't follow the first way of instantiating the class?
2. How would I know to lookout in future  for a similar gotcha?

Comment: `getDateInstance()` is a static method of DateFormat and its doing almost same work except it trying to create DateFormat with the given time and/or date style in the given locale and will check it the instance is already created thus avoid extra work.look the source code of DateFormat for details [DateFormat](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/text/java/text/DateFormat.java.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always consult the API documentation to see how you are to use it.

A `new X()` always create a new object so if you have multiple places you need it, you end up with multiple X'es which may be inefficient if a single X would do.

The `.getDateInstance()` call is a *Factory* that allow the API to decide by itself whether to return the same X even to multiple callers or a new one to each.  For very expensive but reusable/sharable objects this is the typical way you get them.

The Calendar API was donated to Java a very long time ago and is not as well designed as could be.  These days the typical response to "I have problem X with Calendar and/or java.util.Date" in java is to use the Joda library which *is* well designed.  For new code using Java 8 or later, use the new java.time classes as commented by Basil Bourque.

Comment: Update: The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), its creator, [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen), having gone on to lead [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) defining the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8+. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that the core Java API is poorly designed and inconsistent. There's often no good reason for these inconsistencies, you just need to live with them.

More generally, factory methods like `DateFormat.getDateInstance()` allow the API to select different implementation classes depending on the situation, whereas using a constructor directly means there's no such flexibility.

Incidentally, unless you specifically want a `GregorianCalendar`, then the recommended method for obtaining one is `Calendar.getInstance()`, which will return you a `GregorianCalendar` if your locale is appropriate. Other locales will return different `Calendar` implementations. This would be consistent with your `DateFormat` example.

Comment: @Peter: I didn't say it was, that was just a note I added at the end. I explain the difference in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

1. this is because it's an abstract class more info on that can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html
2. same, look if a class is abstract or not.

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8654806/642706) is correct. Here are some more thoughts.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

[`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) is one of the terrible date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java, designed by people who did not understand date-time handling.

These classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes. The `GregorianCalendar` class is specifically replaced by [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

## Immutable classes

The *java.time* classes are designed to be [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), making them [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

This means you never use `new`. Instead, call factory methods. Read about the [naming conventions on such methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html).

Let’s capture the current moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone). We call `ZonedDateTime.now` to capture the current moment. As you can see in [the source code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/ZonedDateTime.java), the constructor of `ZonedDateTime` is marked `private` to prevent us from instantiating via `new`. Internally to that class, the factory method performs the `new`. You can see for yourself, searching that source code for `new ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

By the way, if you must use a `GregorianCalendar` to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert. See new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myGregCal.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

…and…

```
GregorianCalendar myGregCal = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;
```

---

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]